# Passing function to Component in React

Tags: reactjs, components

Hi the previous answers to similar Questions doesn't help me.

I have the `App` Component:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import Board from "./components/Board";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    condition: true
  };
}

onButtonClick() {
  console.log("clicked...");
  this.setState({
    condition: !this.state.condition
  });
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Menu condition={this.state.condition} />
      <Board />
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

the `MenuIcon` Component:

```
  import React from "react";
  import "../css/main.css";

  class MenuIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Menu_icon" onClick={this.props.onButtonClick}>
          <div className="Menu_icon_element" />
          <div className="Menu_icon_element" />
          <div className="Menu_icon_element" />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default MenuIcon;
```

and the `Menu` Component

```
import React from "react";
import "../css/main.css";

class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.condition ? "Menu inactive" : "Menu active"}>
        <ul>
          <li>Notes</li>
          <li>Erinnerungen</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
import React from "react";
import "../css/main.css";

class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.condition ? "Menu inactive" : "Menu active"}>
        <ul>
          <li>Notes</li>
          <li>Erinnerungen</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

and the Header Component

```
import React from "react";
import "../css/main.css";
import MenuIcon from "./MenuIcon";

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Header_container">
        <MenuIcon onButtonClick={this.props.onButtonClick} />
        <div className="Header_headline">Notes</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

I want to trigger the `onButtonClick` defined in **App.js** every time when I click on the `MenuIcon`. And then the `Menu` should fade in or out. The animation is done with css.

I dont find my mistake?

Could someone please help me?

Comment: what is your console output?

Comment: What `MenuIcon` are you clicking on?  Looking at your code, you never use `MenuIcon` in any of your HTML.

Comment: Try to connect your components. Update your question if you have any errors by then

Comment: @seethrough there is no console output.

Comment: @PatrickSteele in the MenuIcon Component is the onClick Event and the MenuIcon is placed within my Header Component. I will Post my Header component, too